# How to send command to the hyperterminal(TCP/IP Communication) from c#.

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0, icsharpcode

In our .net application i want to send some commands to the barcode scanner using **TCP/IP** connection.If i send command from **hyperterminal** to the scanner, the scanner is responding and giving result. In c# code i am using `TcpClient` class to communicate with the scanner. If i send any command to the scanner from my code its not responding. So i want to send command to the hyperterminal from c#.

Comment: Please post your code so everyone can investigate where your problem is

Comment: Why not just fix your code? Hyperterminal doesn't have any special magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Com Port control in your C# project and set the baud rate and party checking and then you can send/receive over the COM interface.

I am not sure this is what you are looking for because you did not give me more details